# jQuery get a smooth update of li elements Ajax

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

Im wondering how I can implement a smooth autocomplete ul, The problem is that whenever it is updated it blinks, By smooth I mean that it does not blink, to be more precise to act like the one of google, everytime you type something, the list of results is updated without blinking.

My code:

```
    $("#uname").on("input", function () {
        let data = {"name": $("#uname").val()};
        $(".suggested-names ul li").remove(); //remove previous results
        $.ajax({
            url: "searchInDB.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                for(var key in response){
                    $(".suggested-names ul").append("<li>" + response[key] +"</li>"); //update results
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

The css:

```
    .suggested-names{
    min-width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
.suggested-names ul{
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0px;
    box-shadow: #8c8c8c 0 4px 3px 0;
}
.suggested-names li{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding:5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #0f0f0f;
}
.suggested-names li:hover{
    background: #eeeeee;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.suggested-names li:last-of-type{
    border: none;
}
```

My code makes a request to a PHP script that returns an array of strings, each time the user writes or deletes something it is updated up it doesn't look very good, It blinks and I can't figure out how to fix it, It would be awesome that you could help me.

And also if there is a better way to do what Im trying to do I'm opened to listen to your ideas. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a smooth autocomplete. You haven't actually asked a specific question.

Comment: Mmm I see, let me edit my question. Alright now its edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest removing the elements from the `ul` only in the `success` function because AJAX is asynchronous and there's a delay between the removal and insertion of the elements.

```
$("#uname").on("input", function () {
    let data = {"name": $("#uname").val()};
    $.ajax({
        url: "searchInDB.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $(".suggested-names ul li").remove(); //remove previous results
            for(var key in response){
                $(".suggested-names ul").append("<li>" + response[key] +"</li>"); //update results
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/botimoo/dvqc6bt9/2/) demonstrating the principle.

**Note:** jQuery deprecated the `success` function so in the future consider using `.done()` instead.

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

**Also note** that if `response` is an array and not an object you shouldn't use the `for(var ... in ...)` for loop, it's consider better practice to loop trough it with a regular for.
And if it is an object, you should test for `response.hasOwnProperty(key)`, otherwise it will match any user-defined properties which extend the `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot for your answer, It responds the question and adds very important details, you are awesome!